# unity3d-Find angle between 3 vector3 points obtained from swipe

Tags: unity, vector, angles

I was trying to find the angle between 3 vector3 points obtained from the screen swipe. The first vector3 point is the first touch position fp, the second is some intermediate touch ip and the third, the final touch position lp.

I tried the unity's Vector3.angle to get the angle but I was getting some angle even if I swiped in a straight line.
Here is what I tried

AB = ip-fp

BC= lp-ip

Then I applied Vector3.angle(AB, BC) but the result is not what I'm looking for.
Any solutions?

Comment: In what way is the result off? The problem might be the vectors' direction. (Something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/1JaDVsv.png).) How's the angle between `BA` and `BC`?

Comment: If I swipe in a straight line, the angle shud be 0,however it's not...it is around 100. I'm not able to make out what's wrong

Comment: Did you check that the issue isn't with their directions?